# Recarregar Datatable após deletar registro

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jquery-datatables

estou com um problema com meu JS. Tenho um datatable e tenho 3 botões para visualizar, editar e excluir um item do banco. Ao clicar no botão excluir, ele dá a caixa de confirmação normalmente, e ao clicar em OK ele apaga no banco, funciona normalmente mas não atualiza automáticamente o datatable, só dando refresh na página com o f5. Como procedo?

```js
<script> 

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#listar_solicitacao').DataTable({

                    "language": {
            "url": '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.12.1/i18n/pt-BR.json'
        },

                    "order": [[0, 'desc']],
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": "../conexoes/listar_solicitacoes3.php"
                    
                });

            });

            async function apagarUsuario(id_solicitacao){

var confirmar = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja apagar a solicitação " + id_solicitacao + "?");

                if (confirmar) {
                    
                
                //console.log("Acessou: " + id_solicitacao);
                const dados = await fetch("../conexoes/deletar.php?id=" + id_solicitacao);
                const resposta = await dados.json();

                


                }         
                location.reload();
                
           
                
            }

            

            

            
    
        </script>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar a **dataTable** em uma variável assim `var table =  $('#listar_solicitacao').DataTable({ ...` e no **confirm** faz `table.ajax.reload(null, false)`. E coloca isso dentro do `if`. Pode ver mais na documentação: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas sem sucesso Andrade, somente retirando o await da linha é que funciona. Vou pesquisar pra ver o que eu tô errando. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de atualizar a página dando reload, é melhor apenas remover o a linha da tabela via javascript mesmo com o método do proprio DataTable 'remove'.

Você pode até declarar algums métodos globais e reutilizar em toda a sua aplicação. Em javascript faça o seguinte:

```
let tab_methods = {
    getline: (table, column, value) => {
        table.rows()[0].forEach((item) => {
            if(tabela.row(item).data()[column] == value) 
                return tabela.row(item);
        });
    },
    delete: (selector, column, value) => {
        let table = $(selector).DataTable();
        let row = tab_methods.getline(table, column, value);
        row.remove().draw();
    }
};
```

Você declara essa variavel acima globalmente e reutiliza da seguinte forma:

```
tab_methods.delete("#tabela", 0, 23);
```

Na linha acima o primeiro parâmetro é o seletor da tabela na qual deseja remover uma linha, o segundo parâmetro é o indice da coluna ou sejá se a sua tabela tem as colunas:
[   ID    |    Título    |    Excluir   ]
Passando o indice '0' irá utilizar a coluna 'ID' como filtro. E o terceiro parâmetro é o valor que deseja excluir no exemplo, a linha de Id igual a '23'.

Com o código acima, sua função ficaria assim:

```
function apagarUsuario(id_solicitacao) {
    var confirmar = confirm(`Tem certeza que deseja apagar a solicitação ${id_solicitacao}?`);
    if(confirmar) {
        $.ajax({
             method: "Post",
             url: "../conexoes/deletar.php",
             data: { id: id_solicitacao }
        }).done(response => {
            tab_methods.delete("#listar_solicitacao", 0, id_solicitacao);
        }).fail(fail => {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro inesperado durante o request!")
        });
    }
}
```

Você pode fazer com ajax ou com fecth mesmo que ocupa menos linhas. Espero que ajude!

Answer (score -1):

a forma que consegui foi retirar o await da linha const resposta = dados.json()". Nesse caso pode ficar assim? Funcionou mas está dando refresh na página e não só recarregando o DT.